# Moment not returning date range

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I am trying to create a date array between 2 dates.

```
[11/16/2018, 12/16/2018, 1/16/2019......11/16/2019]
```

I have the following code.

```js
function dateRange(stDate, etDate) {
  const dates = [];
  var startDate = moment(new Date(stDate)).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
  var endDate = moment(new Date(etDate)).format("MM/DD/YYYY");

  var now = new Date(startDate);
  while (startDate <= endDate) {

    dates.push(new Date(now));
    now = now.addMonths(1);
  }
  console.log("dateRange " + dates);
}

function RunLedgerAndPV() {
  var stDate = "11/16/2018";
  var etDate = "11/16/2019";
  dateRange(stDate, etDate);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Trying to debug it, it doesn't break or anything and it is returning the just the start and end date but doesn't push the date array. What am i doing wrong here?

Also, i have looked at the other posts regarding this and i have myself worked on date range in the past. However, i am clueless as to why this isn't working for me.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: there are a couple of problems here, but the logic is flawed in relation to the `dateRange()` function. It is called as part of an assignment statement but doesn't return anything. In addition, the function modified what seems to be a global. Need to fix these first.

Comment: @Durga My question is not how but what i am doing wrong in the code. And i have also mentioned that in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few inefficiencies and bugs in your code, too many to list really. A summary would include unnecessary creation and then re-stringifying of dates, unnecessary use of JS Date constructors and dodgy logic in your for loop.

Here's a version which will work correctly using just momentJS functionality:

```js
function createLedger(stDate, etDate) {

  if (stDate && etDate) {
    var endOfLeaseDate = moment(etDate, "MM/DD/YYYY");
    var startOfLeaseDate = moment(stDate, "MM/DD/YYYY");
    dateRange(startOfLeaseDate, endOfLeaseDate);
  }
}

function dateRange(stDate, etDate) {
  var dates = [];

  var now = stDate.clone();
  var day = stDate.date();

  while(now.isBefore(etDate)) {
    //deal with variable month end days
    var monthEnd = now.clone().endOf("month");
    if (now.date() < day && day <= monthEnd.date()) { now.date(day); }

    dates.push(now.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
    now = now.clone().add({ "months" : 1 });
  }
  console.log(dates);
}

function RunLedgerAndPV() {
  var stDate = "12/31/2018";
  var etDate = "12/31/2019";
  createLedger(stDate, etDate);
}
RunLedgerAndPV();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work. Suppose my startDate is "1/30/2019", then adding a month until endDate should return "1/30/2019, 2/28/2019, 3/30/2019..." and so forth.

Comment: are you talking specifically in the case of dates toward the end of the month, where e.g. 30th doesn't exist in Feb so it gets you 28th, but then next time it just goes to 28th March, but you wanted it to go to 31st? Or are you claiming it "doesn't work" at all? Please be a bit clearer about what you actually expected it to do. In the original question you didn't give details such as this, you just said you wanted an array - it was left to us to even work out the basic fact that it should be 1 entry per month.

Comment: Yes.In case of Feb it would go till 28th, but next month would go till March 30 (not 31st). I am trying to add 1 month to the startDate every time. Another example, if my startdate = 12/31/2018, then my array will be [12/31/2018,1/31/2019,2/28/2019,3/31/2019....

Comment: Ok I see, thanks. I have edited the answer - please try it again. The demo now runs with end-of-month days so you can see.

Comment: you mean the output format? the input format is already mm/dd/yyyy. I can't see how the format you're outputting would make any difference to the list of values being output.

Comment: It doesn't. I just need it to be in a certain format but moment.utc worked for me. I just realized that moment prints 1 day less when you change the format to ("mm/dd/yyyy") but thank you again.

Comment: I've still really no idea what you're referring to by "1 day less" or why the format of anything would change such a thing (formats are just human notions - moment doesn't store anything in a specific format internally) but I'm glad you got it to work the way you needed.

Comment: If i want the date range based on endDate, how do i do that? Suppose, endDate = 11/17/2019 and startDate = 11/20/2018. Date range = 11/20/2018, 12/17/2019, 1/17/2019 ...11/17/2019.

Comment: Just reverse the whole process to start from the end and work backwards. Off the top of my head (untested): `var now = etDate.clone();
  var day = etDate.date(); while(now.isAfter(stDate)) { ...  now = now.clone().subtract({ "months" : 1 });` Fairly sure you wouldn't have to change anything else. You might have to mess with the month-end stuff a bit, I don't know. Try it, if you're still stuck after that, please ask a new question instead of continually leeching off this one - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (var i=0; now <= endDate; i++) {
     dates.push(new Date(now));
     now = now.addMonths(1);   
 }
```

you instantiate and use `i` in order to loop through nothing. the condition `now <= endDate` is in no way affected by the value of `i` ( typically you increment / decrement `i` until it reaches the desired value as : `var i=0; i < 11; i++` ) i dont event know how this would work, my first instinct is that it will generate a loop that wont stop until until we reach that `endDate` date.

You seems to be looking for getting all the date between a specific range, try the following :

```
var enumerateDaysBetweenDates = function(startDate, endDate) {
   var dates = [];

   var currDate = moment(startDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY');;
   var lastDate =  moment(endDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY');;

   while(currDate.add(1, 'months').diff(lastDate) < 0) {
    console.log(currDate.toDate());
    dates.push(currDate.clone().toDate());
   }

   return dates;
};
```

Comment: Yes. It should've been the 'startDate'. I updated my code. Your 'startOf' doesn't work and throws the following error: "moment.min.js:1 Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions"